# overflow:auto on outer div hides box-shadow of inner div

Tags: css

I have two nested `<div>`s. The outer one has a fixed dimension & the inner one adjusts to the size of content. The inner div has box-shadows that bleed outside the outer div.

Refer to the [JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/saptarshi17/rk0rm1mr/).

```css
.outer {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #fef1f1;
}
.inner {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f1f1fe;
  box-shadow: 2px 5px 8px rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 2px 5px 8px rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 5px 8px rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
  border-radius: 10px;
}
#outer1 {
  left: 100px;
  top: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
}
#outer2 {
  left: 400px;
  top: 100px;
}
#inner2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer1" class="outer">
  <div id="inner1" class="inner">
    Not much stuff<br />to need a<br />scrollbar
  </div>
</div>
<div id="outer2" class="outer">
  <div id="inner2" class="inner">
    Lots of stuff<br />stuff<br />stuff<br />stuff<br />stuff
    <br />stuff<br />stuff<br />stuff<br />stuff<br />stuff
  </div>
</div>
```

In the left example, this works fine because there is no scrollbar required. But in the right box, we need a scrollbar `overflow-y:scroll|auto` and that blocks the shadow. How do I show both the scrollbar and shadow?

Comment: You can add `padding-right: 10px;` to your outer2 div.

Answer (score 0):

Set the overflow to the inner container instead of to the outer one, and also add `max-height: 100%`

```css
.outer {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  height: 150px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #fef1f1;
}
.outer + .outer {
  left: 250px;
}
.inner {
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow-y:auto;
  background-color: #f1f1fe;
  box-shadow: 2px 5px 8px rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 2px 5px 8px rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 5px 8px rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    Not much stuff<br />to need a<br />scrollbar
  </div>
</div>
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    Lots of stuff<br />stuff<br />stuff<br />stuff<br />stuff
    <br />stuff<br />stuff<br />stuff<br />stuff<br />stuff
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But for a shorter content, the box-shadow does not fit the content, it fits the entire area which is not what I want.